# How to respond to "who created God" when debating with an atheist?

Tags: dawah, atheists, atheism

If I'm in a debate with an atheist and then it comes to the point when he says "Then who created God?", how should my response or answer be?

Comment: Have you attempted to do any research before asking? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/where-does-allah-come-from/11784#11784 + http://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=who+created+god + https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=who+created+allah&oq=who+created+allah  + https://www.google.com/search?q=who+created+god

Comment: But these don't answer my question, these answer if a believer is questioning that question, an atheist doesn't even believe God exists, and believes all this is just coincidence, i asked because i was expecting somone who had a successful experience with an atheist particularly to answer.

Comment: no matter what ever you say, when an atheist doesn't believe in God, then what the use how hard you try. Faith is that line which he needs to cross, from believing "*all this exists by coincidence*" to "*someone created what ever exists*". God guides all.

Comment: But "someone created what ever exists" CAN be proved by scientific and historical facts/proof. And you can show those proof to an atheist, and if he denies those, he denies science and rational thinking. Islam is not just "faith", it's also proof. Why would there otherwise be SO MANY converts, who converted BECAUSE of the proof. So when an atheist doesn't believe in God, convince him otherwise. If he still doesn't believe in God, then let it go. But know that he made a fool out of himself, and that has nothing to do with the one who gives dawah. Correction: God guides whom He wants. Sura 2:142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

Atheists tend to ask this question to Muslims. "Who created God"?

God is the first, with no beginning, and the last, but with no ending. So the answer is that God was never created in the first place. He was there. That's it. Here's a video that will explain this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zVpw2-OD4M

> Fully accepting the oneness of God is to accept that He is distinct from everything else. It would not suit God’s majesty and glory to associate the limited attributes of His creation to Him because He is not restricted in any way, while His creation is. **He is the First with no beginning and the Last with no end.** Everything in the universe was created by His will. He is not confined by space or time and He is the only One who is in control and provides for His creation.

Source: http://www.whyislam.org/submission/concept-of-god-submission/concept-of-god-in-islam/

That site will also help you on this regard, and how to talk to atheists in general.

I really hope this helps, and Allah knows best.

Peace be unto you.

Comment: Jazak Allahu khayran brother, that was really helpful, especially the website, I really appreciate it, baraka Allahu feek.

Answer (score -1):

Not that we can define God, but we know some of its attributes.

I think what you should do first is define what God is. 
when we say الله الصمد it means God doesn't need ANYTHING. ( don't read the verse *to him* but convey the message :D )

Whatever that is in need is *created* and therefore weak. There is only 1 entity in this world that is *not* in need and that is Allah.

Having that said. Depending on your situation. I recommend never ever engage in a discussion when one is not asking but rather making statements. Did this person come to asking about God or did you go to him assert your ideology?

If he comes to you then give him all you got. The moment you see him saying nonsense then that's the moment where you stop the discussion and not proceed.

In addition don't make statements. Ask him questions. Don't say There is a God. Ask him how do you think this universe was created. Keep asking questions until you see either his *fitra* (*فطره*) comes out, or you see him conceal *کفر* his fitra.